# Postfix and dovecot unable to receive or send mails

Tags: server, email, postfix, dovecot

I'm trying to setup smtp server for my website on my Ubuntu server, I have successfully installed postfix and dovecot and configured them (at least how I understood from tutorials), but I have encountered a problem that my smtp server is not sending or receiving messages. The most strange thing is that postfix seems to be handling emails (take a look on a log file below). Also if I try to login in my server's email account through microsoft mail application I receive an error that certificate from my server is invalid and also if I press to ignore it application asks me to re-enter passord every 30-60 seconds. Here are my logs

```
Sep  7 19:44:23 stormcraft postfix/pickup[1079156]: 069581E401FD: uid=0 from=<root@stormcraft.online>
Sep  7 19:44:23 stormcraft postfix/cleanup[1079226]: 069581E401FD: message-id=<20230907194423.069581E401FD@stormcraft.online>
Sep  7 19:44:23 stormcraft postfix/qmgr[1079157]: 069581E401FD: from=<root@stormcraft.online>, size=415, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Sep  7 19:44:23 stormcraft postfix/smtp[1079228]: connect to gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com[2a00:1450:4010:c01::1b]:25: Network is unreachable
Sep  7 19:44:24 stormcraft postfix/smtp[1079228]: 069581E401FD: to=<fannylord999@gmail.com>, relay=gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com[64.233.161.27]:25, delay=1.2, delays=0.09/0.05/0.36/0.75, dsn=5.7.26, status=bounced (host gmail-smtp-in.l.goo>
Sep  7 19:44:24 stormcraft postfix/cleanup[1079226]: 3E8E81E401FE: message-id=<20230907194424.3E8E81E401FE@stormcraft.online>
Sep  7 19:44:24 stormcraft postfix/bounce[1079230]: 069581E401FD: sender non-delivery notification: 3E8E81E401FE
Sep  7 19:44:24 stormcraft postfix/qmgr[1079157]: 3E8E81E401FE: from=<>, size=3619, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Sep  7 19:44:24 stormcraft postfix/qmgr[1079157]: 069581E401FD: removed
```

I have also checked if port 25 is opened on my machine by establishing telnet connection with gmail server, connection was established successfully, so it seems to be opened... I've also tried to send and receive email on email of different email provider, but it didn't make a trick. This situation looks pretty weird for me so I will appreciate any help.

Comment: Due to a quarter century of disrespectful email spam tactics, most ISPs and cloud storage providers block attempts to set up email servers. The necessary ports will be blocked at the network level by whoever is supplying the connection to the internet. If this is something you want to do yourself, you’ll need to get in touch with the appropriate provider and plead your case. Some will open the ports, some will expect additional fees, others will outright refuse as a bad actor on their IP range can result in a complete block from other email providers.

Comment: First of all, I appreciate you spending your time for answering my question. Is there any way to check if the problem is on the side of my server configuration or on the side of my ISP? I'm not using cloud storage for this service, I have just my own machine running over static IP address from my ISP. As I said, telnet connection over port 25 seems to be getting established successfully so I want to determine on with side the problem is before contacting my ISP

Comment: Also I'm receiving log entries on attemts to send or receive an email so it doesn't seem to be blocked to me

Comment: you'll have to use something like AWS because of what matigo explained.  Frankly, you're better off paying someone ten bucks a month...it's a fairly common service to offer.